# Rename .app and using the new name with open -a

Tags: zsh

I want to change the name of Visual Studio Code to vscode for using the command `open -a vscode`. Any idea how?

Comment: Can‘t you just define a shell alias for this? If not, which problem are you trying to solve by this?

Comment: I know this solution, but I was curious if there wasn't another one

Comment: Have you tried typing the word Code from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a symbolic link:

```
cd /Applications
ln -s Visual\ Studio\ Code.app vscode
```

You can then open it with:

```
open -a /Applications/vscode
```

Answer (score 2):

When I installed VSCode on my machine it installed something for the command line.  If I type the word `Code`, from the command line, VSCode starts up.

There is a command in the Command Palette that will do the link for you. Go to command palette, under the view menu, and there is a command that says `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH.`Click on this and it sets up a link from Applications/vscode to /usr/local/bin.  After that, you can just type code to run the program.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work as advertised! I just downloaded **Visual Studio Code** from [https://code.visualstudio.com/download](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and installed it (unzipped **VSCode-darwin-stable.zip** to **/Applications**), opened it and closed it. Then in **Terminal** typed `Code` and it errors with: `zsh: command not found: Code`

Comment: ok, it worked fine for me. can you try it using the bash shell?  Unless you've already found an answer.  I'll look to see where code is defined on my system. Maybe that will help you.

Comment: Shouldn't have to try `bash` as `zsh` is the default _shell_ in a clean install of **macOS Catalina**, however, it too errors: `-bash: Code: command not found` Did you by chance create an _alias_ or _sysmlink_?

Comment: i found a link.  but in VSCode there is a command in the command palette that says: Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH. maybe that's how I did it. It creates a link for you. I don't remember for sure how I did it. If I had done it manually I would not have called it code. lol. Probably vscode. Go to the View menu in VSCode and select Command Palette.  Under that you'll see the command.  Maybe easier to do link yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to make the necessary changes to be able to type `open -a vscode` in **Terminal**, why not just add the following to your **~/zprofile** *file*, e.g.:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH"
```

Then all you have to do in **Terminal** to open **Visual Studio Code** is type `code` and press **enter**.

See **Launching from the command line#** in [**Visual Studio Code on macOS**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) for additional details.

[image]